# rectangle and circle moving together

Tags: javascript, raphael, draggable

I am new to raphael js.
I am creating a rectangle and some circle inside that rectangle in row and column manner. Number of circle depends on user input given in popup form.
Now I want to drag all the elements means rectangle and circles by dragging rectangle.
How can I achieve this.Can anyone help me in doing this.

Comment: You would probably have to write a custom drag handler, so it transforms other elements in a set of the elements for example. If you don't need older browser support, you could try Snap.svg which is very similar, but also has group support (so you can drag whole groups easier).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add all elements into a set together and then drag the set?

This is what i'm using to drag sets:

http://jsfiddle.net/Margo/Q3EBw/5/

```
paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500); var ox = 0; var oy = 0; 
var screenSet= paper.set(); screenSet.push(paper.rect(0, 0, 100, 75, 0).attr({
        fill: 'red', stroke: 'none'
    }));

screenSet.push(paper.text(0 , 0 ,"Text").attr({ "text-anchor": "start" }));
start = function() {

    ox =  this.attr("x");
    oy = this.attr("y");
    screenSet.attr({
        opacity: 1
    }); },

move = function(dx, dy) {
    var att ={
        x: ox + dx,
        y:oy + dy
    };
    screenSet.attr(att);
},
up = function() {
    this.attr({
        opacity: .5
    });
    ox = 0, oy = 0;
}; screenSet.drag(move, start, up);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I use a rect and text here in example but you can easily do the same with rect and circle, let me know if it works for you!